# How to search for attributes using Elementtree in python

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm a little confused on how Elementtrees work in Python as the following code is not working:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file = ("People.xml")

tree = parse(file)

myList = tree.findall("person")

for people in myList:
   print people.attrib["name"]
   jobs = people.findall("jobs/job")
   for job in jobs:
      print job.attrib["title"]
```

I get an error saying `AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'attrib'`.  How is jobs a different type of object than people as they both are items from a list returned from `findall`?

Sample xml file is:

```
<person name="p1">
   <address>address1</address>
   <jobs>
     <job title="title1">job1</job>
     <job title="title2" pay="pay1">job2</job>
   </jobs>
</person>
<person name="p2">
   <address>address2</address>
   <jobs>
     <job title="title3">job3</job>
     <job title="title4" pay="pay2">job4</job>
   </jobs>
</person>
```

The reason I need to do a search of the nature I am attempting is that I am trying to print the names of people whose jobs have the "pay" attribute set to pay2.

Comment: you should avoid calling your variables 'list' as it is a built-in python type, also providing some excerpt of the content of the xml file may help.

Comment: Just performing a simple `print people` may be of some help.

Comment: I concur with the recommendation not to name your variables "list", but your code still works for me as is, if I put "ET." before "parse" and wrap the XML doc in a single toplevel element. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Updated my code here and on the system :)  I'm running 2.6